# On click of button div display 1 by 1 (single at a time)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have 10 `<div>` with the same class. I want  Only 2 div visible when the page load and after clicking on a load more button the next div should show. This way after click on every load more button the next single hide div should display.

I have tried with below code but unable to success.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#loadmore" ).click(function() {
        $(".design-derection").one( "div" ).show();
    });
    </script>
```

Html Structure is

```
<div class='content-block'>
<div class='design-derection'></div>
<div class='design-derection'></div>
<div class='design-derection'></div>
<div class='design-derection'></div>
<div class='design-derection'></div>
<div class='design-derection'></div>
<div class='design-derection'></div>
<div class='design-derection'></div>
<div class="view-more" id="loadmore">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">View More Ranges</a>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide HTML and Js code in a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6FzSb/

Comment: https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/sGkvH

Comment: @AmiteshKumar on load more I want to display only single div

Comment: you can manipulate the code.check my answer now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
$( "#loadmore" ).click(function() {
    $(".design-derection:visible").last().next().show()
});
```

Just target the last visible div and after that the next one and show it.

Comment: after all div load how to hide the load more button

Comment: @Narayan you should write yourself an `if` that will check if the length of `$( "div:visible" ).last().next('div')` is greated than 0. If it's 0 than you will hide it.

Comment: Yeah thanks drip. I have hide load more button with this code `if($(".design-derection > *").filter(":hidden").size()==0){
            $("#loadMoreRanges").hide();
        }`

Answer (score 1):

[Js fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/5292/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myList">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
        <li>Seven</li>
        <li>Eight</li>
        <li>Nine</li>
        <li>Ten</li>
        <li>Eleven</li>
        <li>Twelve</li>
        <li>Thirteen</li>
        <li>Fourteen</li>
        <li>Fifteen</li>
        <li>Sixteen</li>
        <li>Seventeen</li>
        <li>Eighteen</li>
        <li>Nineteen</li>
        <li>Twenty one</li>
        <li>Twenty two</li>
        <li>Twenty three</li>
        <li>Twenty four</li>
        <li>Twenty five</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
    <div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+1 <= size_li) ? x+1 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-1<0) ? 1 : x-1;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
 #myList li{ display:none;
    }
    #loadMore {
        color:green;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    #loadMore:hover {
        color:black;
    }
    #showLess {
        color:red;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    #showLess:hover {
        color:black;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  size_li = $(".design-derection").size();
  x=2;
  $('.design-derection:lt('+x+')').show();
  $('#loadmore').click(function () {
    x= (x+1 <= size_li) ? x+1 : size_li;
    $('.design-derection:lt('+x+')').show();
 });

});
```

and added a line of css

```
 .design-derection{ display:none;}
```